# Client patch gives 400 error in django testing

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-views

So basically when i try to **test** my patch view it doesn't patch at all as **i get a 400 error**. However, when i call the same patch view **outside** the APITestCase, while running the test server, it does work.

#### what i've tried:

- patch_data = json.dumps({'first_name': 'test999'})
- format='json'

**At APITestCase:**

```
    def test_patch_update_data(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
        self.assertEqual(self.user.first_name, 'Robert')
        patch_data = {'first_name': 'test999'}
        response = self.client.patch('http://testserver/api/patch/{0}/'.format(
            self.user.id), patch_data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) # ERROR:GIVES 400!
        self.assertEqual(self.user.first_name, 'test999')
```

**At views.py**

```
class UsuariosUpdatePatchAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Usuarios.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsuariosUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsSelfUser]
```

#### The error:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: DRF provides meaningful content about why a 400 happens. What's the response content ?

Comment: for partial updates add partial=True   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates

Comment: @Linovia thanks! response.data printed that 'fisrt_name' was actually alpha only, so 'test999' wasn't accepted. So changing to 'example' worked as it doesn't contain any numbers!

Comment: However, 'first_name' isn't affected after successful patch, faling at *self.assertEqual(self.user.first_name, 'example')* but that's a whole new question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How silly i am:

As stated in the comments, **response.data** gives very useful information. It turned out to be that the field *fist_name* only accepted letters! So the solution was changing *test999* to something without numbers!